# Using plugins with Cordova CLI

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

I'm using Cordova CLI (v6.0.0) to make an app for Android and I can't load the plugins: cordova-plugin-file and cordova-plugin-dialogs. I know it because the next alerts are shown:

```
if (!navigator.notification)
    alert("Plugin notification not working properly!");

if (!window.requestFileSystem)
    alert("Plugin file not working properly!");
```

Plugins are used after clicking a button (not before ondeviceready event).
Plugins have been installed with:

cordova-plugin-file v.1.2.0

```
 cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
```

cordova-plugin-dialogs v4.1.0

```
 cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs
```

I've also added the next line in config.xml

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you should install direct git link of plugins its better.

Comment: But the problem persists...

Comment: Are you waiting for cordova `deviceready` event?? [Link to docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.0.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html)

Comment: I don't use the plugins at the beginning of the app, but when I click a button.

Comment: Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next line, in the main html file, was missing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```